# ListView click event not triggered when clicking on empty areas

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, events

I have a `ListView` control on my form. I have set its display mode to `LargeImageList`. I need to handle the items inside this control. So I have written code for its `click` event. But I see now that this event is not triggered when I `click` in an empty area inside it.

How can I make my `ListView` aware of the clicks on its area regardless.

Comment: I think you will have to use the MouseDown/MouseUp events to catch those particular click events.

Comment: @Ulric same story with MouseDown.

Comment: Hmm...it works on my machine. I get the same issue you have with the MouseClick and Click events, but MouseDown works for me regardless of if I click a space or an item.

Comment: Can you share a bit of code ? It would be easier for us to help you...

Comment: Use MouseDown instead, ListView.HitTest() to discover what was clicked.

Comment: @Ulric You were right. I added my code to both `MouseDown` and `MouseUp` event. You can post your comment as answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To capture mouse clicks on the "white space" around the ListView items, you will need to use the MouseDown/MouseUp events.

This will also capture clicks to the items as well.

Answer (score 0):

I've used the Global Mouse Hook for similar issues. You can use it to detect Mouse Clicks anywhere on the screen, then just check the click was within the listview control bounds.

Grab the code from [Global Mouse Key Hook](https://github.com/gmamaladze/globalmousekeyhook)

```
IKeyboardMouseEvents m_GolbalHook = Hook.GlobalEvents();
m_GolbalHook.MouseClick += m_GolbalHook_MouseClick;


private void m_GolbalHook_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (listView.Bounds.Contains(e.Location)) && (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left))
    {
         //Do Stuff
    }
}
```